# How to change property of more than one qlineedit at once

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have done some coding for `L00` (name of my first `QLineEdit`).

I want to do the same for other 99 widgets (up to `L99`). I don't wanna copy paste it 100 hundred times.

```
void MainWindow::on_L00_returnPressed(){
    QString c = ui->L00->text();
    char d = QString(c).at(0).toLatin1();
    if(d>=65&&d<=90||d>=97&&d<=122)
    {
        square[0]=d;
        ui->MessageBox->setText("Alphabet succesfully entered");
        ui->L00->setReadOnly(true);
        ui->L00->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(0, 255, 255);}");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->MessageBox->setText("Enter Alphabets Only");
        ui->L00->setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Find all of the relevant `Qlineedit`s and use a loop.

Comment: Have you all added QLineEdit through QT Designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add all these widget through `Qt Designer` the objects will have the same name of the variable, so we can get them through `findChild`, then apply connect the signal `ReturnPressed` to a lambda function and not having to create a slot for each `QLineEdit`.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    int n = 100;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        QString name = QString("L%1").arg(i, 2, 10, QChar('0'));

        QLineEdit* w = findChild<QLineEdit *>(name);
        connect(w, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [=](){

            QString c = w->text();
            char d = QString(c).at(0).toLatin1();
            if((d>=65&& d<=90)||(d>=97&&d<=122))
            {
                square[i]=d;
                ui->MessageBox->setText("Alphabet succesfully entered");
                w->setReadOnly(true);
                w->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(0, 255, 255);}");
            }
            else
            {
                ui->MessageBox->setText("Enter Alphabets Only");
                w->clear();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

*Note: I have considered that `square[i]` corresponds to the `QLineEdit` L-i.*

Another solution is to connect all to the same slot and obtain the object through the function sender().

***.h**

```
private slots:
    void onReturnPressed();
```

***.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    for(QLineEdit* w: findChildren<QLineEdit *>()){
        connect(w, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &MainWindow::onReturnPressed);
    }
}

void MainWindow::onReturnPressed()
{
    QLineEdit* w =qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(sender());
    int i = w->objectName().remove(0, 1).toInt();
    QString c = w->text();
    char d = QString(c).at(0).toLatin1();
    if((d>=65&& d<=90)||(d>=97&&d<=122))
    {
        square[i]=d;
        ui->MessageBox->setText("Alphabet succesfully entered");
        w->setReadOnly(true);
        w->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(0, 255, 255);}");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->MessageBox->setText("Enter Alphabets Only");
        w->clear();
    }
}
```

## For old version:

***.h**

```
private slots:
    void onReturnPressed();
```

**.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    int n = 100;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        QString name = QString("L%1").arg(i, 2, 10, QChar('0'));
        QLineEdit* w = findChild<QLineEdit *>(name);
        if(w)
            connect(w, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(onReturnPressed()));
    }
}


void MainWindow::onReturnPressed()
{
    QLineEdit* w =qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(sender());
    int i = w->objectName().remove(0, 1).toInt();
    QString c = w->text();
    char d = QString(c).at(0).toLatin1();
    if((d>=65&& d<=90)||(d>=97&&d<=122))
    {
        square[i]=d;
        ui->MessageBox->setText("Alphabet succesfully entered");
        w->setReadOnly(true);
        w->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(0, 255, 255);}");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->MessageBox->setText("Enter Alphabets Only");
        w->clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty so much for the answer,but u must have noticed i am an amateur. QString name = QString("L%1").arg(i, 2, 10, QChar('0'));                                    what this line does can u plz explain?

Comment: Let's say I have the index i = 6, then with that statement I generate the string "L06", padding the intermediate space with zeros if necessary, since if i = 11 it would not be necessary since the string would be "L11"

Comment: In the specific case: `QString("L%1").arg(i, 2, 10, QChar('0'));` `%1` is where the result is placed, `i` is the index placed, `2` is the number of characters to be placed, `10` is the numerical basis to be used, `QChar('0')` are the characters that will be used to fill the empty spaces.

Comment: at first i just copy pasted the whole code,it didnt work.It says                          error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QLineEdit*&, void (QLineEdit::*)(), MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::<lambda()>)'.There are more errors this one is the 1st.                              I am trying to understand ur code now

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: i am using 5.0.2

Comment: I could help if you share your code through github, dropbox or similar, also that you indicate the version of Qt.

Comment: Your version is very old, in that version lambda versions are not supported, I will add code for your version.

Comment: What is this line doing                                                                                            QLineEdit* w = findChild<QLineEdit *>(name);
           connect(w, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [=]()

Comment: I'm looking for the children of the main widget that are QLineEdit and then I'm connecting to a lambda function.

Comment: I will download the latest version then,What is lambda function?:-(

Comment: A lambda function is a function that you can declare locally without having to give it a name, it serves to create functions that you only use once.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax.                                                          it says somethng bout the old syntax,can u plz give the codes in the older syntax if possible

Comment: Exactly, I've used the new syntax.

Comment: I will update my answer for old versions, wait a moment please.

Comment: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::returnPressed() to MainWindow::onReturnPressed().                                                                      
The program run without error but it doesnt do anything.

Comment: If my answer helps you please mark my answer as correct please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`QObject::findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) to do so. It must be called from the parent widget (your `MainWindow`). You can from it connect the `QLineEdit` individually, or change all values at once.

Example:

```
for (auto lineEdit : this->findChildren<QLineEdit*>()) {
  // connect lineEdit or change values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem starts with:

> I have done some coding for L00 (name of my first QLineEdit) … 99 widgets (up to L99).

This means that you designed your application incorrectly.

I'm almost sure that you should use `QTableView` or `QTableWidget` with `QAbstractTableModel` or `QStandartItemModel`.

Also `setStyleSheet` should be applied on `QApplication` or at least on top level widget. This is how stylesheet is supposed to be used.